# perl Zipping a folder without the working directory file path

Tags: regex, perl, zip, compression

I am trying to compress a folder containing files and subfolders (with files) into a single zip. I'm limited to the core perl modules so I'm trying to work with IO::Compress::Zip. I want to remove the working directory file path but seem to end up with a blank first folder before my zipped folder, like there is a trailing "/" I haven't been able to get rid of.

```
use Cwd;
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);

my $cwd = getcwd();
   $cwd =~ s/[\\]/\//g;

print $cwd, "\n";
my $zipdir  = $cwd . "\\source_folder";
my $zip = "source_folder.zip";

my @files = ();

sub process_file {
    next if (($_ eq '.') || ($_ eq '..'));
    if (-d && $_ eq 'fp'){
        $File::Find::prune = 1;
        return;
    }
    push @files, $File::Find::name if -f;
}
find(\&process_file, $cwd . "\\source_folder");

zip \@files  => "$zip", FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd|| }  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

I have also attempted using the option "CanonicalName => 1, " which appears to leave the filepath except the drive letter (C:). 
Substitution with

```
s[^$dir/][]
```

did nothing and

```
s<.*[/\\]><>
```

left me with no folder structure at all.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**
[image: Resultant Zip contents (blurred to protect the innocent) in 7Zip]

The Red level is unexpected and is what is not required, win explorer is not able to see beyond this level.

Comment: Seems like you are working on Windows.
Can you try this : 

    `zip \@files  => "$zip", FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd\\|| }  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";`

Comment: Have you looked at the results of your substitution(s)? `s<.*[/\\]><>` leaves you with no folder structure at all, because it greedily gobbles up everything up to the last backslash. Maybe you want to just remove `length $cwd` characters from the start of `$File::Find::name`? Please edit your post and show us concrete input filenames, output filenames you get, output files you want and the resulting zip structure you want.

Comment: @GMB is this different from the method used in the first part of my code? The `s|\Q$cwd\\||` substitution removes the working directory however it leaves behind a pair of // which translate to an initial folder folder 'invisible' to windows explorer. I can view them with 7zip or similar, however, the systems this will be run on need them to be visible in windows.

Comment: @Corion, I realised that this was greedily removing the entire path. I attempted the length $cwd method with substring `zip \@files  => "$zip", FilterName => sub{ substr($_, 0, length($cwd))}  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";`. Unfortunately this gives me the same result as `s|\Q$cwd\\||`. 
I will try to find a way to present the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with your script.

First, you are mixing Windows and Linux/Unix paths in the script. Let me illustrate

I've created a subdirectory called **source_folder** to match your script

```
 $ dir source_folder
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 7CF0-B66E

 Directory of C:\Scratch\source_folder

26/11/2018  19:48    <DIR>          .
26/11/2018  19:48    <DIR>          ..
26/11/2018  17:27               840 try.pl
01/06/2018  13:02             6,653 url
               2 File(s)          7,493 bytes
```

When I run your script unmodified I get an *apparently* empty zip file when I view it in Windows explorer. But, if I use a command-line unzip, I see that source_folder.zip isn't empty, but it has non-standard filenames that are part Windows and part Linux/Unix.

```
$ unzip -l source_folder.zip
Archive:  source_folder.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      840  2018-11-26 17:27   \source_folder/try.pl
     6651  2018-06-01 13:02   \source_folder/url
---------                     -------
     7491                     2 files
```

The mix-and-match of windows & Unix paths is created in this line of your script

```
find(\&process_file, $cwd . "\\source_folder");
```

You are concatenating a Unix-style path in **$cwd** with a windows part "\source_folder".

Change the line to use a forward slash, rather than a backslash to get a consistent Unix-style path.

```
find(\&process_file, $cwd . "/source_folder");
```

The second problem is this line

```
zip \@files  => "$zip", 
        FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd|| },
        BinmodeIn =>1
   or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

The substitute, `s|\Q$cwd||`,  needs an extra "/", like this  `s|\Q$cwd/||` to  make sure that the path added to the zip archive is a relative path. So the line becomes

```
zip \@files  => "$zip", FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd/|| }  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

Once those two changes are made I can view the zip file in Explorer and get unix-style relative paths in when I use the command-line unzip

```
$ unzip -l source_folder.zip
Archive:  source_folder.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      840  2018-11-26 17:27   source_folder/try.pl
     6651  2018-06-01 13:02   source_folder/url
---------                     -------
     7491                     2 files
```

Comment: Sorted! Thank you!

Comment: So, I have the compressing working, but I have an issue with 2 files which report as corrupted when they are extracted. The files are .xlsx and .pdf files. Is there a particular setting I should apply to prevent this?

Comment: Try adding *binmode =>1* to the zip line. So becomes *zip \@files  => "$zip", BinModeIn => 1, FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd|| }*

Comment: Thank you, and apologies for the super delayed response. I just updated the code with this extra argument and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
use Cwd;
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;
use IO::Compress::Zip qw(:all);
use Data::Dumper;

my $cwd = getcwd();
$cwd =~ s/[\\]/\//g;

print $cwd, "\n";
my $zipdir  = $cwd . "/source_folder";
my $zip = "source_folder.zip";

my @files = ();

sub process_file {
    next if (($_ eq '.') || ($_ eq '..'));
    if (-d && $_ eq 'fp') {
        $File::Find::prune = 1;
        return;
    }
    push @files, $File::Find::name if -f;
}
find(\&process_file, $cwd . "/source_folder");
print Dumper \@files;
zip \@files  => "$zip", FilterName => sub{ s|\Q$cwd/|| }  or die "zip failed: $ZipError\n";
```

I changed the path seperator to '/' in your call to find() and also stripped it in the FilterName sub.
console:

```
C:\Users\chris\Desktop\devel\experimente>mkdir source_folder
C:\Users\chris\Desktop\devel\experimente>echo 1 > source_folder/test1.txt
C:\Users\chris\Desktop\devel\experimente>echo 1 > source_folder/test2.txt
C:\Users\chris\Desktop\devel\experimente>perl perlzip.pl
C:/Users/chris/Desktop/devel/experimente
Exiting subroutine via next at perlzip.pl line 19.
$VAR1 = [
      'C:/Users/chris/Desktop/devel/experimente/source_folder/test1.txt',
      'C:/Users/chris/Desktop/devel/experimente/source_folder/test2.txt'
    ];

C:\Users\chris\Desktop\devel\experimente>tar -tf source_folder.zip
source_folder/test1.txt
source_folder/test2.txt
```

Comment: Hi @clamp, Please can you present your results of the final zip file? This is the code I provided which doesn't produce a workable result in windows with an additional print statement.